# How to differentiate from multiple interpretations of the word "language"

Tags: word-usage, synonyms, terminology

Suppose I'm currently writing an introduction to programming languages. One of my paragraphs start as follows:

> Everyone can learn how to program. It is like learning a new **language**. [...]

In this sentence, by **language** I mean Spanish, English, French, etc. This kind of language.

But as the reader, how would you know that? **Language** may be referencing a programming language or a speech language (Spanish, English ...).

Of course, if it'd mean a programming language, the sentence will make not sense, so the reader will opt for the other alternative.

But consider a translation program or software which the only information available to it is the context of the text. Judging by the context, it'd be consitent that I am refering to programming languages. So it'll be translated accordingly.

In Spanish, we have a specific word for speech languages, which is **idioma**.
This word will remove the ambiguity and the reader can now know exactly what I mean.

But there isn't a similar word in English (nor that I know of, of course). I'm not proficient at it, but "**idiom**" seems like a totally different thing from me than its spanish translation.

When saying or writing the word "**language**", how can I explciitly differentiate from a programming language, or a "speech language", or any kind of different language?

Comment: The usual English equivalent to Spanish's *idioma* is [*natural language*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language) and indeed computer programs such as your hypothetical translator that try to identify the intended gloss of a word from its context fall under the discipline of *Natural Language Processing*, or NLP.

Comment: When you use the word "language" outside of a computer context, only the most isolated nerd would take that to mean "programming language".

Comment: 'natural language'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A programming language (such as C++) is referred to as **a programming language.**

A language (e.g. English, German, Swahili, Chinese, etc) is referred to as **a language**.

Shakespeare did use the word *tongue* a lot, but using it today is not advisable. Some folks might get resentful and start giving you weird looks.

That's all there is to it.

Comment: I think "tongue" is a fairly good way of avoiding the ambiguity in this particular sentence: "... It is like learning a new tongue."

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to make sure your meaning is properly understood would be to say:

Everyone can learn how to program. It is like learning **to speak** a new language. [...]

Answer (score 1):

> how can I explciitly differentiate from a programming language, or a "speech language", or any kind of different language?

Where needed, I would clarify that I'm either talking about a **[spoken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoken_language)** language, a **written** language, a **programming** language, a **sign** language, or a **mathematical** language etc.